# Sylius No css and images, nothing in /web/assets directory

Tags: sylius

i just installed Sylius, all seems to be ok but when i launch `app_dev.php`, I have no css and JS.

I checked `/web/assets/` : directory is empty

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: This has been answered in other questions on SO and in the issues area of sylius. You need to install `npm`. Then run `npm install` in your base directory. Then run `gulp` And also run `php app/console assets:install`

Answer (score 2):

## Installing assets

In order to see a fully functional frontend you will need to install its assets.

Sylius already has a `gulpfile.js`, therefore you just need to get Gulp using Node.js.

Having Node.js installed go to your project directory and run:

```
$ npm install
```

And now you can use gulp for installing views, by just running a simple command:

```
$ npm run gulp
```

Although if you have Gulp installed globally then run just:

```
$ gulp
```

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/installation/installation.html#installing-assets

Answer (score 0):

you have to run gulp, see "**Installing assets**" : 
http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/installation.html#installing-assets